# Копирование связанных данных Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mvvm

Есть база данных, со связанными таблицами. Entity Framework Code First

Таблица 1.

```
    public class Student
    {
    public Student()
    {
        CourseWork = new ObservableCollection<CourseWork>();
        StateAtt = new ObservableCollection<StateAttestation>();
        AddInfo = new ObservableCollection<AdditionalInformation>();
        Practice = new ObservableCollection<Practice>();
        Discipline = new ObservableCollection<Discipline>();
        Electives = new ObservableCollection<Electives>();
    }
    private ObservableCollection<CourseWork> _courseWork;
    private ObservableCollection<StateAttestation> _stateAtt;
    private ObservableCollection<AdditionalInformation> _addInfo;
    private ObservableCollection<Practice> _practice;
    private ObservableCollection<Discipline> _discipline;
    private ObservableCollection<Electives> _electives;

    public virtual ObservableCollection<CourseWork> CourseWork
    {
        get { return _courseWork; } set { _courseWork = value; }
    }

    public virtual ObservableCollection<StateAttestation> StateAtt
    {
        get { return _stateAtt; } set { _stateAtt = value; }
    }

    public virtual ObservableCollection<AdditionalInformation> AddInfo
    {
        get { return _addInfo; } set { _addInfo = value; }
    }

    public virtual ObservableCollection<Practice> Practice
    {
        get { return _practice; } set { _practice = value; }
    }

    public virtual ObservableCollection<Discipline> Discipline
    {
        get { return _discipline; } set { _discipline = value; }
    }

    public virtual ObservableCollection<Electives> Electives
    {
        get { return _electives; } set { _electives = value; }
    }

    [Key]
    public int StudentID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(265)]
    public string PreviousLevelEducation { get; set; }

    public int RegistrationNumber { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime ExtraditionDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool ExcellentAttribute { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int DiplomSeries { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int DiplomNumber { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int AttachmentSeries { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int AttachmentNumber { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime DecisionDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Qualification { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Specialty { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Lifetime { get; set; }
    }
```

Таблица 2.

```
    public class Discipline
    {
    [Key]
    public int DisciplineID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string DisciplineName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int QuantityHours { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Discipline")]
    public virtual Student discipline { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Rating { get; set; }
    }
```

Как реализовать копирование строки из главной (таблицы 1) и всех связанных строк из таблицы 2 и остальных? Понимаю что нужно заменить все ключи, но реализации в интернете так и не нашел. (Копировать в те же таблицы, но с другими id)

Comment: Копировать куда? При чём тут замена ключей?

Comment: Копировать в те же таблицы, но с другими id

Comment: `Копировать в те же таблицы, но с другими id` - это важное замечание, которое нужно добавить в вопрос!

Comment: @Bulson Добавил

Comment: Иными словами вы хотите создать дублированные записи, или клоны в БД. Обычно от них стремятся избавится, а не специально создать. Мне кажется, что такое проще сделать непосредственно в СУБД с помощью SQL, а не писать для этого программу. Но, если очень надо, то вам всего лишь надо читать взаимосвязанные данные из таблиц, затем делать DeepCloning сущностей (копирование всех свойств, за исключением ID), и потом снова делать запись этих новых клонов в БД как обычных новых данных, а айдишники им будут назначены автоматом при записи. Могут быть проблемы если есть требования на уникальность столбцов

Comment: @Bulson спасибо что навел на мысль, после этого разобрался.